# Removing Panda rows in a Python program where a column value is higher than a constant

Tags: python, pandas, selection

I'm new both to Python and Pandas (and stackoverflow).  I have many large sets of data and in each I want to sub-select rows and then eliminate outliers.

```
    myrawdata = pandas.read_csv(filename,index_col = ("Proc_Trial Type"))
    #
    # Select rows with "Flanker" as the trial type
    #
    mrd2 = myrawdata.loc["Flanker"]
    #
    # Eliminate rows which have "Practice" in the Proc_Shuffle 1 column
    #
    mrd3 = mrd2[-mrd2["Proc_Shuffle 1"].isin(["Practice"])]
    #
    # Create new df, excluding response times > 1000 ms to eliminate outliers
    #
    mrd7 = mrd3[mrd3["Resp_RT"] < 1000]
```

The above all works fine except the last line, which I had hoped would eliminate rows in which the column headed "Resp_RT" has a value greater than 1000.  However, it appears to have no effect.

I have searched online, both within stack overflow and elsewhere to find how to do this without success.  I've also read the panda actions without getting any inspiration.  I'd be grateful for suggestions that might help.

Comment: This should work; could you show some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

The code shown by you works fine and even last line seems to execute correctly. 
`mrd7 = mrd3[mrd3["Resp_RT"] < 1000]`

Comment: Thank you.  I was convinced it wasn't working but I checked and found it was. Computers have a great ability to make me look stupid.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

the way you show does it :)

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Resp_RT':[1,2,3,4,6,1000,1001,1002]})
other = df[df["Resp_RT"] < 1000]
print(other)
```

Comment: I have been frantically busy with other work for two days and just got back to this.  Thank you for your feedback: when I checked (by printing values) I found it was working after all.  Thank you for taking time to reply.